# If $P=NP$, prove that $L' \in NP$

Tags: computational-complexity, formal-languages

I think I'm overthinking this problem and need some hints in the right direction.

The goal of this question is to show that if $P=NP$ then for every language $L \in NP$ via a polynomial time verifier $V$, there is a polynomial time algorithm that given $x \in L$ finds a certificate $x$ satisfying $V$.

Let $V$ be a polynomial time verifier over $\{0,1\}$ such that all strings accepted are of the form $\langle x,c \rangle$ where $x,c \in \{0,1\}^*$.

Let $L \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$ be a language and let $d$ be a positive integer such that for every $x \in L$, there is a string $c$ of length $|x|^d$ such that $V$ accepts $\langle x,c \rangle$ and for every $x \notin L$, there is no string $c$ such that $V$ accepts $\langle x, c \rangle$.

Let $L' = \{\langle x,c_1 \rangle \ |\ x,c_1 \in \{0,1\}^*$ and for some $c_2 \in \{0,1\}^*$, $V$ accepts $\langle x,c_1c_2 \rangle$ and $|c_1c_2| = |x|^d$ $\}$

**Prove that $L' \in NP$.**

My approach would be to show that $L' \le_p L$ by some reduction function however I am not sure of this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is $L$ part of the problem statement? It doesn't seem to enter into the theorem.

Comment: Yes I believe so since it was stated that $L \in NP$.

Comment: @Mario: L' is defined in terms of V and d, which are defined in terms of L, so L is part of the problem.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems that just from definition we have L' in NP, with no need of a reduction or even the hypothesis that P=NP.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I've edited it a bit to include more of the original question but yes this is why I am confused myself, I don't know what exactly this question is asking.

Comment: The question is asking you to prove that L' is in NP. This follows directly from the definition of NP and the fact that V is a polynomial time verifier. Ignore the first paragraph; it's only about the eventual goal, presumably after you prove a bunch of these exercises leading up to it. (What definition of NP do you use in your course?)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i was thinking, the definition we use is that if the language can be verified in polynomial time then its in NP. Since $L'$ has a verifier $V$ then its in $NP$. I guess thats the answer, just thought I was missing something.